# How to use type safe extra properties in Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have multimodule project written in Kotlin DSL. Here are the relevant files:

`rootDir/gradle/dependencies.gradle.kts`:

```
// other config
val libVersion by extra("0.1")
```

`rootDir/build.gradle.kts`:

```
// other config
subprojects {
    apply(from = "$rootDir/gradle/dependencies.gradle.kts")
}
```

And in my subProject I can access dependencies with code:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("group:name:${extra["libVersion"]}")
}
```

Is there a way to access the `libVersion` variable by it's name? I want to declare dependencies in subprojects using code:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("group:name:$libVersion")
}
```

As this will give type-safe link to the property as well as IDE help on property value. One way to do it is to bind variable to the extra property like this:

```
val libVersion: String by extra
```

But this will mean repetition of already declared properties in `extra`. So how to organize dependency versions in subprojects in type-safe manner without repetition of variable names but also with single point of declaration of dependecies versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the code like

```
val propertName by extra {
  //here goes the initializer code
  "the result"
}
```

The `extra{..}` function defines the property for the project with name `propertName` (or the name of the variable)

And you may say

```
val anotherProperty by rootProject.extra
```

to access an extra property of the other project

Comment: How to call multiple variables from `extra`?